# How to pick up a weapon unity 2d using OncollisionEnter2D

Tags: unity-game-engine

Im making a 2D top down unity game. I want to detect collisions between the player and a weapon using OncollisionEnter2D, after the player collide with weapon it will become a child object to the player. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the OnCollisionEnter2D make a Prefab of your Weapon and Instantiate it to your players Position